# How to make the whole input text box full of the whole div

Tags: html, css, input

The diagram below, the green is div and white area is a text box, I want to keep text box full of whole div

[image]

Who can help me? I will be very grateful.

Comment: Can you give the CSS you have used so far please?

Comment: It might be useful to post a snippet of your code so that we can review.
Include the HTML that generates the box, it's parent element, and the CSS that affects them as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set child width and height to 100%

Here is a live demo:

```css
div{
  height:50px;
  width:300px;
  background-color:green;}

div input{width: 100%;height: 100%;}
```

```html
<div><input type="text" name="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If the `div` has a fix width, then add the same width property to your input (text box). If not, then you can set to 100% the width property of your text box.

Answer (score 3):

add `input{width:100%};` to your css

http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/p3qzvgvk/

Comment: if you have more than one type of input then use input[text]{width:100%;}